# Getting custom assembly attributes without loading into current AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I have created a small application to recursively load assemblies in a provided directory and read their custom attributes collection. Mainly just to read the DebuggableAttribute to determine the settings for IsJITTrackingEnabled and IsJITOptimizerDisabled to determine if the assembly is optimized for release.

My current code does an Assembly.LoadFrom to pass-in the entire path to the assembly and load it. Then does a GetCustomAttributes on the assembly to get the debuggable attribute. The problem is that each assembly gets loaded into the current appdomain. So, if another folder uses the same assembly it just uses the originally loaded reference. I would like to be able to load the assembly, read the properties I need, then unload it. I have tries creating a new appdomain and loading the assemblies into it then unloading the assembly afterword to no avail.

I know this must be possible but I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'd be happy to provide any other information you may need as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer is, no, there's no way to do what you're asking.

The longer answer is this: There is a special assembly loading method, [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k.aspx), which uses a "reflection-only" load context. This lets you load assemblies that cannot be executed, but can have their metadata read.

In your case (and, apparently, in every use case I could come up with myself) it's not really that helpful. You cannot get typed attributes from this kind of assembly, only `CustomAttributeData`. That class doesn't provide any good way to filter for a specific attribute (the best I could come up with was to cast it to a string and use `StartsWith("[System.Diagnostics.Debuggable");`

Even worse, a reflection-only load does not load any dependency assemblies, but *it forces you to do it manually*. That makes it objectively worse than what you're doing now; at least now you get the dependency loading automatically.

(Also, my previous answer made reference to MEF; I was wrong, it appears that MEF includes a whole ton of custom reflection code to make this work.)

Ultimately, you cannot unload an assembly once it has been loaded. You need to unload the *entire app domain*, as described in [this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

UPDATE:

As noted in the comments, I was able to get the attribute information you needed via the reflection-only load (and a normal load) but the lack of typed attribute metadata makes it a serious pain.

If loaded into a normal assembly context, you can get the information you need easily enough:

```
var d = a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false) as DebuggableAttribute;
var tracking = d.IsJITTrackingEnabled;
var optimized = !d.IsJITOptimizerDisabled;
```

If loaded into a reflection-only context, you get to do some work; you have to figure out the form that the attribute constructor took, know what the default values are, and combine that information to come up with the final values of each property. You get the information you need like this:

```
var d2 = a.GetCustomAttributesData()
         .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ToString()
                                .StartsWith("[System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute"));
```

From there, you need to check the `ConstructorArguments` to see which constructor was called: [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/adcetswf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with one argument or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k2wxda47%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with two arguments. You can then use the values of the appropriate parameters to figure out what values the two properties you are interested in would have taken:

```
if (d2.ConstructorArguments.Count == 1)
{
  var mode = d2.ConstructorArguments[0].Value as DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes;
  // Parse the modes enumeration and figure out the values.
}
else
{
  var tracking = (bool)d2.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
  var optimized = !((bool)d2.ConstructorArguments[1].Value);
}
```

Finally, you need to check for `NamedArguments` that might override those set on the constructor, using for example:

```
var arg = NamedArguments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MemberInfo.Name.Equals("IsJITOptimizerDisabled"));
var optimized = (arg == null || !((bool)arg.TypedValue.Value));
```

On one final note, if you are running this under .NET 2.0 or higher, and haven't already seen in, MSDN points this out in the [`DebuggingModes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.debuggingmodes%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) documentation:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, JIT tracking information is always generated, and this flag has the same effect as Default with the exception of the IsJITTrackingEnabled property being false, which has no meaning in version 2.0.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that but was having difficulty getting to IsJITTrackingEnabled and IsJITOptimizerDisabled via the CustomAttributeData object. Am I going about that incorrectly?

Comment: Well, I was able to do what you wanted but I also discovered that `ReflectionOnlyLoad` is basically useless. It doesn't automatically load dependencies -- *you have to load them yourself*. (I also discovered that MEF has implemented a custom reflection context, and doesn't appear to use this at all.)

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you managed to get to the properties I need? I am very close and was able to load the assemblies with a delegate. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`.

Here are some [MSDN Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/08/24/219691.aspx) that shows how to use it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

public class ReflectionOnlyLoadTest
{
    public ReflectionOnlyLoadTest(String rootAssembly) {
        m_rootAssembly = rootAssembly;
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Test assemblyPath");
            return;
        }

        try {
            ReflectionOnlyLoadTest rolt = new ReflectionOnlyLoadTest(args[0]);
            rolt.Run();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}!!!", e.Message);
        }
    }

    internal void Run() {
        AppDomain curDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        curDomain.ReflectionOnlyPreBindAssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyReflectionOnlyResolveEventHandler);
        Assembly asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(m_rootAssembly);

        // force loading all the dependencies
        Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();

        // show reflection only assemblies in current appdomain
        Console.WriteLine("------------- Inspection Context --------------");
        foreach (Assembly a in curDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assembly Location: {0}", a.Location);
            Console.WriteLine("Assembly Name: {0}", a.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private Assembly MyReflectionOnlyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
        AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        String asmToCheck = Path.GetDirectoryName(m_rootAssembly) + "\\" + name.Name + ".dll";
        if (File.Exists(asmToCheck)) {
            return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(asmToCheck);
        }
        return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);
    }

    private String m_rootAssembly;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It isn't possible to ever unload an Assembly in the current AppDomain, that is just the way .NET is designed to work unfortunately. This is even the case with ReflectionOnly loads. There is also a slightly wrinkle with doing that as well as you then need to use the [GetCustomAttributesData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcustomattributesdata.aspx) method instead of the normal GetCustomAttributes as the latter needs to run code in the attribute constructor. This can make life more difficult.

An alternative which should work is using [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) which allows you to inspect the assembly without actually loading it in the normal sense. But that is a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad is what you are looking for.